# Backing up a Wordpress/Azure website

Tags: wordpress, azure

My website is created in WordPress and hosted by Azure.

I read in the WordPress documentation that you need to back up the files and the database separately.

In Azure, I upgraded my pricing plan to Standard so that I can do regularly scheduled backups. In Azure, it is divided into "Storage" and "Database".

If I have Azure backups configured, should I still backup with a hard copy? Do I also need to do a backup on the WordPress side of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Azure website backup feature you backup following- 
1. Your web app configurations 
2. Your actual web app file contents(everything that's under your site)
3. The Azure sql or MySQL database - This is optional. i.e. you can choose to back it up or not.

So don't have to backup your site separately.

When you schedule backups you can either schedule a full backup or partial backup using kudu console (if you don't want to back up things such as static content or log files everyday)

These backups are stored in Azure storage containers and one advantage of using this backup service is you have options to directly restore your website from any of the backups.

Also, if you want to take a manual backup and store it to your local hard drive or some other place, you can just download the zip files from backup.

EDIT

You can do that from the storage container that you used to backup the website. Go to browse -> storage accounts -> (your container) and you will find the zip.

[image]

Comment: Where do you find that manual backup that you can download the zip files from?

Comment: Edited my answer above

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend backing up WordPress separately. It's just smart because stuff happens and if you decide to migrate to a faster host later, it'll be easier. If you favor automation from backup to migration, I find those to be superior:

- cPanel Softaculous
- updraft
- managewp.org/plugins/best
- vaultpress

From what I understand though, azure creates app containers. If you backup the entire app/site, your good to go...but why not take things an extra step and backup WordPress too? Maybe it's a bit overkill...but using Drive, AWS or Dropbox is just convenient.

Comment: To do the hardcopy backup I find this in the wordpress console?

Comment: it just depends on what approach you take. if you chose a plugin, most often once you jump into WP Admin you'll see it. for example, updraft is WP Admin > Settings > Updraft. if you chose managewp.com than the backup will be in their web admin control panel + the WP Admin dashboard. vaultpress on the other hand, you can ONLY download the backup from their website because they store all the data.